# Implementing dropdown menu in dynamic table columns in html using jquery/js/python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a program with python that takes a CSV file, filters it and shows it to the user as a filtered file. That works great, but I have a problem when I want to implement dropdown menus for my table.

I used `to_html()`and `<div class="table-responsive">{{data| safe}} </div>` to import the file on the html side as a table.
 I used javascript/jquery to implement the add/remove buttons, search box. What I can't figure out is how to add dropdown menus, since my table is not shown with HTML tags and each time has a different number of rows.

I have 23 columns and only 3 of them should have dropdown menus from which the user should choose a value for each row.

I created a fiddle to show how it looks currently. Bear in mind that here I just hardcoded my table for the example.- I did insert the class and id for the table on the python side so I can access the inputs in the table.

https://jsfiddle.net/2gw09vpr/1/

Currently, I added an attribute `contendEditable` for the columns 4,5 and 6 where there should be a dropdown list to choose from. How can I do that?

I am new to python/jquery/js so I am lost on how to do it.
What I tried so far was similar to this:

[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhE5/50/) ; [fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8gr9qkka/2/) ;[fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sn1z5vzn/7/)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443855/taking-data-from-drop-down-menu-using-flask)

And nothing works for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would the dropdown lists contain?  Are the lists going to be populated by your Python program?  If so, it might help to show the Python code as well.

Comment: the dropdown lists would be filled with the values from arrays example: (``arr1=[a,b,c,d]``)

Comment: Are the arrays in your JavaScript code and you're just looking to see how to populate them?  If so, have you tried something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446086/3830432 ?  If you're looking for something different, I apologize.

Comment: thanks for answering, tried it but it just adds all of the lists in the first row . I need dropdown in each row in the same column

Comment: Can you please post what you tried?  It might help with getting this working.